# oauth 2: Disabling pkce, what are the risks? web app only can I safely disable it?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I've recently had an assignment to incorporate another application into our platform.
I have one login component written in react. I wanted to reuse it for the authentication and only on demand change the redirect url to the second application.
(if this scenerio isn't self explanatory just imagine having a main app with the oauth authentication  and an analytics app or documentation app that needs to go through the same authentication mechanism)
so what's the problem?
problem is with pkce I can't start oauth 2 at one app ending at another site to finish the authentication (without the code challenge created at first app).
I decided to disable pkce as our platform is only meant for web.
so redirect urls kept in my keycloak should be sufficient, and I can complete an oauth at the second app. then I saw that oauth 2.1 https://oauth.net/2.1/ intends on enforcing pkce.
thing is why? I think that security should also take in account ease of development I shouldn't be required to duplicate the login component. am I doing something wrong? should I go with another approach?
thanks for the answers

I developed an app with oauth2 and disabled pkce I thought it's ok that it is optional as it is suppose to help with mobile app, but just saw on the official oauth 2 site that they are intending on enforcing pkce.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the app that initiates the authentication request should also be the one that completes it, otherwise, you are exposing yourself to many risks.

There are several security features that you should check if you want to make sure it is secure according to best practices. PKCE is one of them, but there is also the **state** and **nonce** parameter that you should verify that they match the original values.

I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:

- [Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/)